# undefined method `get' for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to use a bit of code from a Ruby application in Rails.

The application in question is not in Rails and has two views. I copied a part of the code and pasted it in a controller in Rails:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index, :locals => {:item_id => item_id, :access_token => access_token}
end
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `get' for XXXcontroller)
```

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to interpret this bit of code in a controller in Rails.

Comment: It looks like you’ve pasted something from a Sinatra app into a Rails controller. They just don’t work the same way at all. Go and read the [Rails controller documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions) for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with an actual tutorial/book and learn Rails. You can't assemble a rails app out of random snippets that you have no understanding of.

That code is from Sinatra which is designed with simple applications in mind and where your routes and controllers are mushed together into a single file. Rails and Sinatra code is not interchangeable*.

If you want to define a route in Rails for `/` (the root path). You define it like so:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home' 
end
```

And then declare the corresponding controller:

```
# app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

And a view:

```
<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
```

See:

[Getting Started with Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: * At least not controllers / routes.

Answer (score 1):

Routes in a Rails app are located in the  `routes.rb` file in the `config` directory.  Your route might look something like this:

```
get '/index', to: 'controller#index'
```

This says execute the index action of the controller controller. That method (index) is associated with a ‘get’ request.